# Does the F-word constitute a third of all swearing on the internet?

Tags: language, internet

[This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L77gk5QEZFo) (created as part of a series of short programmes for the UK's Channel Four television called [Susie Dent's guide to Swearing](http://www.channel4.com/programmes/susie-dents-guide-to-swearing)) claims (around 3:08 in) that the word "fuck" makes up about a third of all swearing on the internet.

Is there a source behind this estimate? Is is just a guess or has someone actually done some research?

PS what a joy to live in a country that has a TV programme called Susie Dent's Guide to Swearing!

Comment: How would you even measure this? To me, "on the internet" includes private text and voice and also gigahours of untranscripted streamers…

Comment: Can you name more sources that claim this? A single YouTube video with the opinion of an individual isn't really enough to get me into _investigation-mode_ :P

Comment: @BlueWizard It's more than a youtube video: it is a TV programme on a major UK network by a well-known personality.